# How to limit the user to certain urls in webview?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air

I have created an adobe air application. I have integrated facebook in my application.

Now when the facebook login page opens in the webview, user has the option to use "Forgot your password" and "Sign Up" links. I want to prevent the use of these links.

I am using LOCATION_CHANGED and LOCATION_CHANGING events to detect the browsing of the user. How can i prevent this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using event.preventDefault()? I think that should stop the web view from redirecting. Perhaps you can evaluate the url the view is trying to go to and selectively call preventDefault() then?

Comment: Yes. I tried it but the url does not change on locationchanging for "forgot your password". I get the url for it in the handlelocationchange.